# How can I set this？

Tags: python-3.x, django

I am new to django.

> it is very important that django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder be there in your STATICFILES_FINDERS.

resource:https://django-admin-tools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html#installing-django-admin-tools

Where are

> STATICFILES_FINDERS

> django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder

Comment: The `STATICFILES_FINDERS` setting is in your Django site's `settings.py` file.  See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#staticfiles-finders.  *"How can I set this?"* - by editing the file.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [**`STATICFILES_FINDERS`** <sup>[django-docs]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#staticfiles-finders):

> Default:
>
> ```py
> [
>     "django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder",
>     "django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder",
> ]
> ```
>
> The list of finder backends that know how to find static files in various locations.

And this means `"django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder"` already has been set in project settings as `STATICFILES_FINDERS`, and you don't need to do anything.